# Ruby on Rails, count records of certain types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 different types of records. Let say 4 records are of type A, 1 record is of type B and 10 of type C. Some users have only A and B, and others all 3 types.

First, I need to retrieve the types, and then count how many records have the type A, B or C.

Is it possible to make it in one call, so that I get a `Hash` from the database like following:

```
 A:4, B:1, C:10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User.group(:type).count
=> {"A"=>4, "B"=>1, "C"=>10}
```

Comment: I mean, is it possible to do something like this: User.group(:type).count.each do |n,m| puts(n,m)?

Comment: @Katja Yes you can iterate like this: `User.group(:type).count.each do |type, count|`